# Why do I have an undefined when I try to read object[key].value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want something similar to this :

```
Cars {
    "test-01-test" : {
        brand: 'anybrand',
        color: 'blue,
    }
```

I want Cars as an Object and the id "test-01-test" as an Object too.

So I can read it like that :

```
console.log(this.cars["test-01-test"].color) //result should be blue
```

I tried this in my data function

```
cars : {
        id : {
            brand : '',
            color : '',
        }
    }
```

and then in my mounted in I wrote this  :

```
    this.cars.id = "test-01-test";
    this.cars.id["test-01-test"].color="blue";
    console.log(this.cars);
```

But the console says that :

> Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

I want to set-up the color and the like my first exemple, how can I do ?

What I'm trying to do, is the add IDs dynamically. If I do something like this (imagine I ask the users with a modal to insert a new car with a new id):

```
this.cars[id] = "test-02-test" //test-02-test was given by the user's input
```

I want to create a new object with the value "test-02-test" and then put the color and the brand so my data looks like this :

```
Cars {
    "test-01-test" : {
        brand: 'anybrand',
        color: 'blue,
    },
    "test-02-test" : {
        brand: 'anybrand',
        color: 'blue,
    }
```

Comment: If `id` is a variable, you have to write `this.cars[id]` not `this.cars.id`

Comment: `this.cars[id].color`

Comment: Ok, this is for the reading part, but how can I setup the id? My object is empty in my mounted, and I want to add him an ID (test-01-test) and then the color blue and the brand.

Comment: Just delete this line `this.cars.id = "test-01-test";`

Comment: Not exactly what I'm trying to do, sorry! I edited my question my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is:

```js
let cars = {
  id: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  }
};

cars.id = "test-01-test";

console.log(cars);
```

Instead you should do:

```js
let cars = {
  id: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  }
};

console.log(cars);
cars.id.color = "blue";
console.log(cars);
```

or dynamically:

```js
let cars = {
  peugeot: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  },
  citroen: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  }
};

let id = 'citroen'
cars[id].color = "blue";
console.log(cars);
```

You can add a new id like below:

```js
let cars = {
  peugeot: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  },
  citroen: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  }
};

let id = 'ford'
cars[id] = {
  brand: '',
  color: '',
};
console.log(cars);
```

or with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
let cars = {
  peugeot: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  },
  citroen: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
  }
};

cars = {...cars, dodge: {
    brand: '',
    color: '',
    }
}
console.log(cars);
```

Comment: But I have to wrote the IDs my self ! I want the ID part to be dynamically... like If I have a modal with this text "Add a new id : ____" and I write " Add a new id : Tesla". How can I add this new ID?

Comment: @JohnW2Smith I've added 2 ways of adding ID's

Answer (score 0):

Your ID is a key inside this object

Try:

```js
let cars = {
  "test-01-test" : {
    brand : 'anybrand',
    color : 'blue',
  }
}
console.log(cars["test-01-test"].color)
// Output: blue
```

Comment: Not exaclty what I'm trying to do, I edited my question ! Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Because identifier is case sensitive.
A function define in global scope, 'this' refer in this function window object, when you access 'this' in function it refer window.cars. So, window.cars is not equal to window.Cars.